# Change The System Partition, Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

my computer originally attached with two hard disk (disk1 as C: and disk2 as E:) where disk1 is SATA (system partition) and disk2 is IDE (boot).

then, i attached another hard disk (disk3 as D: , which is SATA) because disk1 is only 50GB and nearly full.

my questions:

1. what should i do to transfer everything from disk1 to disk3?
2. is it necessary to transfer everything in disk1?
3. do i need to change the system partition from disk1(C:) to disk3(D:)?
4. and what is the best way?

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy/move data from Dist1 to Dist3 then you may use disk 3 through external hard drive converter.

Copy data from your desktop and My documents directly and paste them all into drive D:/